# angularjs ng-show div open for a second after page refresh

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-show, angularjs-ng-show

I have a angularjs bug. I think this are common angular bugs. After a page refresh, you will see the {{variable}} before compiling.

Or you see the div which should be shown after a variable is true. And that is my biggest problem. I have a timepicker. This is disabled and should only pop up after the user will click a button. But it will pop up for a while when i refresh the site. 
Here are two screenshots.

This pops up after i refresh the page
[image]

And this is the timepicker after clicking a button

[image]

Here is my code:

HTML Part

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  Hello, {{hello}}!

  <button ng-click="openTimepicker()">
  Open Timepicker
  </button>

  <div ng-show="uhrzeitanzeigen" class="uhrzeitContainer menu" click-outside="closeThis()" outside-if-not="timepicker">
            <div class="uhrzeitwaehlenContainer">
                Uhrzeit wählen:
                <p>{{stunden}}:{{minuten}}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="uhrzeitWrapper">

                <div class="uhrzeitStunden">
                    <div class="stunde" ng-class="{'clickedBorder': getStunde($index)}" ng-repeat="i in getNumber(number) track by $index" ng-click="clickStunde($index)"><span>{{$index+1}}</span></div>

                </div>

                <div class="uhrzeitMinuten">
                    <div class="minute" ng-class="{'clickedBorder': getMinute($index)}" ng-repeat="i in minutenAnzeige track by $index" ng-click="clickMinute($index)"><span>{{i}}</span></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="buttonContainer">
                <a class="uhrzeitButton" href="">Abbrechen</a>
                <a class="uhrzeitButton" href="">Ok</a>
            </div>
        </div>

</div>
```

AngularJS Code

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

//myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {});
//myApp.factory('myService', function() {});

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.hello = "Welcome =>";

  $scope.uhrzeitanzeigen = false;
    $scope.stunden;
    $scope.minuten;

    $scope.awesome = true;

    $scope.number = 24;
    $scope.getNumber = function(num) {
        return new Array(num);   
}

    $scope.openTimepicker = function() {
        $scope.uhrzeitanzeigen = !$scope.uhrzeitanzeigen;
    }

    $scope.closeThis = function() {
        $scope.uhrzeitanzeigen = !$scope.uhrzeitanzeigen;
    }

    /* Methoden für die STUNDEN */

    $scope.stundenArray = [];
    $scope.clickStunde = function(index) {
        for(var i = 0; i < $scope.number; i++) {
            $scope.stundenArray[i] = false;
        }
        $scope.stundenArray[index] = true;
        $scope.stunden = index+1;
    }

    $scope.getStunde = function(index) {
        console.log("get stunde");
        return $scope.stundenArray[index];
    }

    /* Methoden für die Minuten */
    $scope.minutenArray = [];
    $scope.minutenAnzeige = ['00', '15', '30', '45'];

    $scope.clickMinute = function(index) {
        console.log("click minute " + index);
        for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            $scope.minutenArray[i] = false;
        }
        $scope.minutenArray[index] = true;
        $scope.minuten = $scope.minutenAnzeige[index];
    }

    $scope.testvar = true;

    $scope.getMinute = function(index) {
        console.log("get minute");
        console.log($scope.minutenArray);
        console.log($scope.minutenArray[index-1]);
        return $scope.minutenArray[index];
    }

})
```

the css code

```
.uhrzeitContainer {
    background-color: white;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20%;
    left: 25%;
    width: 50%;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 7px 18px -5px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 7px 18px -5px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    box-shadow: 0px 7px 18px -5px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}

.uhrzeitwaehlenContainer {
    background-color: #3F51B5;
    color: #E8EAF6;
    padding: 5%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 25px;    
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.uhrzeitWrapper {
    display:block;
    overflow:auto;
}



.uhrzeitStunden {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    width: 60%;
    float: left;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
}

.uhrzeitMinuten {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    width: 40%;
    float: left;
}

.stunde, .minute {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 20px 22px 20px 20px;
    text-align: center;
}

.clickedBorder {
    background-color: #3F51B5;
    color: white;
}

.buttonContainer {
    float: right;
}

a.uhrzeitButton {
    color: #3F51B5;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 5px 15px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Here is a [jsfiddle with the code](https://jsfiddle.net/TorbenG/k74phb96/6/). But there is no bug at jsfiddle. i dont know if it is okay to link my website but [there is the code with the bug](http://testumgebung.torbengabriel.de/PharmAD/oeffnungszeiten.php). (click the input field)

I hope someone could help me and knows this kind of bug...

Comment: try adding ng-cloak like:  <div ng-cloak ng-show="uhrzeitanzeigen"

Comment: it works, ha :) nice very nice, i love you !!!! thanks. But why? crazy bug? my mistake?

Comment: ng-cloak will hide your HTML content until your controller is fully loaded

Comment: thanks so much :) i am really happy :)

Answer (score 3):

Use `ng-cloak` so that your directive will be applied once the data is fully loaded. It is same as `window.onload`. i.e. your function will be called once the window in loaded.

```
<div ng-cloak ng-show="someValue" >
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For a simple solution.. on your datetime container css class (uhrzeitContainer) , set it's display property to none.

The ngShow directive works with the display property and having it default to not visible may solve your problem with no fuss :)

Comment: ng-cloak will do the work for you. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak